# Is it possible to display and hide buttons in a php echo inside script?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My problem is I cannot show or hide the button when the data value change to `Delivered`.

here is my php code

```
<?php 
    $cardstatus = $row['cardStatus'];
    if($cardstatus == NULL){
       echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">Card Pending</span>';
    } elseif($cardstatus == 'Delivered') {
       echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Delivered</span>';
     //Display Done Button
       echo '<script>document.getElementById("done").style.display = "block";</script>';
    //Undisplay Close Button
       echo '<script>document.getElementById("cancel").style.display = "none";</script>';

     } else {
       echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">In Process</span>';
   }


?>
```

My Button below

```
//Button Cancel
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm cancel" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-user="<?php echo $row['user'] ?>" id="cancel">Cancel</button>

//Button Done
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm done" style="display: none;" id="done">Done</button>
```

My Ajax

```
    action: function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "accept.php",
                            data: {
                                addInfo: addInfo,
                                passInfo: passInfo,
                                id:id
                            },
                            dataType: "text",
                            success: function (data) {
                                // window.location.replace("purchased-top-up-cards.php");
                                $('#done').show(); //This will show but will be gone after refresh
                                $('#close').hide(); //This will hide but will show after refresh

                            },
                            error: function (err) {
                                console.log(err);

                            }                       
                        });
                    }
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You cannot use php to change the status on an existing page without loading a new page or getting the status using ajax.

Comment: If buttons are rendered __after__ js script, this will not work.

Comment: @mplungjan when I use ajax after success, if I refresh the previous button will show and it will go back again to the previous buttons. i mean it is just temporary after success til I refresh

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea what you just wrote means.

Comment: @mplungjan can you wait I'll just edit my ajax what i've written previously? It worked tho but it is just temprarily till i refresh

Comment: @mplungjan I've edited my code sir please take a look at my ajax

Comment: can you not do `<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm done" style="display: <?php echo ( $cardstatus == 'Delivered' ? 'block' : 'none' )?>;" id="done">Done</button>`?

Comment: @RamRaider - sir you are correct it worked but the other button didnt work can you please make it an answer below please. thank you

Comment: @RamRaider - it works but the cancel button must be hidden and done button must be shown when it is 'Delivered'

Comment: just extend the same logic but in reverse ( as it were ) to the `cancel` button

Comment: @RamRaider sir i'm not familiar with the `?` and `:` syntax ;( sorry kindly explain please.

Comment: @wanotema https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator - did you take a look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Too little info. I would expect you have a php that can do the following:

```
<?php 
  $cardstatus = $row['cardStatus'];
  if($cardstatus == NULL){
     echo '{ "type":"warning" , "text":"Card Pending" }';
  } elseif($cardstatus == 'Delivered') {
     echo '{ "type":"success" , "text":"Delivered" }';
   } else {
   echo '{ "type":"info" , "text":"In Process" }';
  }
?>
```

and on the client

```
$(function() {
  $("#someForm").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel form
    $.post("accept.php",{ "addInfo": addInfo, "passInfo":"passInfo","id":id },function(res) {
      $("#someContainer").append('<span class="badge badge-pill badge-'+res.status+'>'+res.text+'</span>');
      $("#done").toggle(res.status=="success");
      $("#cancel").toggle(res.status!="success");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `var = test ? 1 : 0` is known as a [`Ternary Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and is approximately the same as `if/then/else`

In the code below a simple test `$cardstatus == 'Delivered'` is used as the condition to the ternary operator and the appropriate value is then echoed depending upon the value stored in the variable.

```
echo ( $cardstatus == 'Delivered' ? 'block' : 'none' )
```

is a more concise equivalent of

```
if( $cardstatus == 'Delivered' ) { echo 'block'; } else { echo 'none'; }
```

So, applying that same logic inline to the HTML elements but reversing the `block/none` for the cancel button should work.

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm done" style="display:<?php echo ( $cardstatus == 'Delivered' ? 'block' : 'none' )?>;" id="done">Done</button>

<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm cancel" style="display:<?php echo ( $cardstatus == 'Delivered' ? 'none' : 'block' )?>;" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-user="<?php echo $row['user'] ?>" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

hope it helps...